# Salesforce lightning component with Highchart

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, json, highcharts

My requirement is to rebuild apps in Lightning component.Currently in existing apps , we have charts developed using Highchart.So anyone know if Lightning can be integrate with Highchart?If possible, please provide reference on this.

If this question considered  improper, let me know so I can delete it right away.

Comment: On another level, Salesforce have [charts.js library](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBarPEAT) that was added back in June 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Highcharts or any other libraries with lightning.

First you need to upload your libraries (highcharts & jquery) as static resources to your org. To do that you go to Setup | Develop | Static Resources. You can learn more about it on [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm) .

It might work with CDN too as http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, but you might have problems with dependencies.

Once you have your libraries uploaded they will be available to you under `/resources`. You can then load then to your component and/or app using `<ltng:require />`.

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/jquery, /resource/highcharts, afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.AMethodOntheComponentController}" />
```

Comment: One of my colleague tried it , and it 's working good.Just a challenge that we might have number of chart dynamically so we need to figure out how to dynamically create the layout.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using Highcharts and Highmaps in our org within Lightning Components and we've found a big problem while using Highcharts and Highmaps in the same Lightning App or Community or context. 
Highcharts has a problem loading in single page app structures and sometimes it does not load any map and it throws Highcharts error #16. 
However, if you are only using Highcharts you might not find any problem.

[Error #16 loading Highcharts with Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116886/error-16-loading-highcharts-with-lightning-components/116912#116912)

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Error #16 loading Highcharts with Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116886/error-16-loading-highcharts-with-lightning-components)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Static Data: You have to upload your libraries i.e highcharts & jquery as static resources to your org. You have to go Setup | Develop | Static Resources.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, if you want to fetch real time data in high chart then you have to think by using external object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/164188)