# Can we create bar chart in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to display bar chart in lightning component? If it is possible then any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

You might also find Highcharts to be a good fit - see my answer [Error #16 loading Highcharts with Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116886/error-16-loading-highcharts-with-lightning-components) that has a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can use a few External JS Libraries like:

- ChartJS
- D3.js
- Google Charts.

If you need a fairly simple and easy to build charts, then i suggest using Google charts.
Check the link below for brief documentation on this from google:
[Google Bar Charts Overview](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#overview)