# Highcharts chart not rendering if LockerService is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, highcharts

LockerService was enabled as a critical update in my DE org. I am trying to create a home page showing multiple charts using Lightning component and Highcharts as charting library.

The charts are rendered fine if I deactivate the LockerService. 
I get this error if LockerService is active and I try to render highcharts chart:

Something has gone wrong.

> Error in $A.getCallback() [NotFoundError: Failed to execute
>   'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this
>   node.] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AHM_Home1}. Please try again.

I am using Highcharts version 4.2.3

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishn/g81q2vtx/)

@doug I also tried running the example mentioned at this link

[Error #16 loading Highcharts with Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116886/error-16-loading-highcharts-with-lightning-components)

A chart is rendered but x-axis categories are not rendered. Also when I move cursor over the bars in chart, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
>   throws at /resource/1466446420000/Highstock/js/highstock-all.js:172:157

The screenshot shows the resulting chart as per the sample at the above link:

[image: Bar chart using Highstock in Lightning]

Comment: Hi @AshishNarkhede
Any updates on this? I'm still not able to make Highcharts 5 work (which is strict mode compatible) when Locker Service is activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the problem using this simple application:

```
<aura:application >
    <ltng:require scripts="{! $Resource.Highstock + '/js/highstock-all.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
    <div aura:id="chart" class="slds-box slds-box--small"></div>
</aura:application>


({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: component.find("chart").getElement(),
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }],
        });
    }
})
```

I've noticed that the chart appears to draw properly, except for labels. This JS error occurs on hover:

*Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.*

I've opened a bug to track getting this fixed.

Comment: Thank you @JF Paradis ! I look forward to updates on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide the following details to enable us to reproduce this problem?

- Highcharts version
- A simple version of your code illustrating the
  problem

We are actively increasing exposing more of the DOM API in LockerService, with the aim to keep the system secure and transparent. I personally have not seen Highcharts used with LockerService yet, but we should be able to quickly investigate this case and give you an update.

Comment: I've edited the question with the details you asked for. Thank you!

Comment: JF we have automation covering Highcharts (see TrevorB for details) and the error above is not something we've seen before with or without Highcharts. That DOM level error could be a case where the LS proxy is not getting unwrapped and is being sent directly to the raw removeChild()? Also took a quick look at the sample code and nothing jumps out there - very similar to our automated sample too.

Comment: @DougChasman I've updated the question with some more information. Kindly take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @JF is this been resolved? I'm getting the same issue when I activate lockerservice critical update :(

Comment: Hi @Ranga, you should not have to apply the critical update. It has been delayed one release. We are taking the time to properly testing some libs, and I will post when I have a complete picture.

Comment: Highcharts 5 now implements strict mode:
https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/15056937-ensure-compatibility-with-javascript-strict-mode?tracking_code=26beabdeec07692d05ea6bf0acac1b14

Comment: Hi @JFParadis I'm currently using version 5 of highcharts which implements strict mode. But when Locker Service is activated, I get an error saying "[Can't find variable: Highcharts]". Were you able to use Highcharts 5 when Locker Service is activated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the LockerService enforcement is creating a problem here. Actually, LockerService creates a secure custom DOM which creates it's custom window object too. Are you using scripts in ltng:require? if not then please update your code. For more discussion about this, you can check [Salesforce blog on LockerService](http://Actually,%20it's%20happening%20due%20to%20new%20changes%20introduced%20by%20the%20Salesforce%20after%20enabling%20the%20LockerService%20in%20your%20org.%20LockerService%20creates%20it's%20own%20custom%20DOM%20(%22secureDOM%22)%20and%20custom%20Window%20object%20too.%20Due%20to%20custom%20window%20object%20you%20are%20likely%20to%20see%20these%20behaviors%20of%20JS.%20%20For%20more%20details%20please%20refer%20the%20following%20blog.%20[Salesforce%20blog%20about%20LockerService][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html).