# Unable to render charts with jQuery and Flot.js libraries when LockerService is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service

I've been using [Flot.js](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to render some charts inside lightning components and everything worked fine until the new LockerService update was activated. As far as I researched, many people have had similar issues

[Highcharts chart not rendering if LockerService is enabled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128010/highcharts-chart-not-rendering-if-lockerservice-is-enabled)

[LockerService in Lightning Components is blocking Canvas element color fill completely](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/lockerservice-in-lightning-components-is-blocking-canvas-element-color-fill-comp#128548)

[Can't set element.style.properties in JS inside Lightning Locker](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127032/cant-set-element-style-properties-in-js-inside-lightning-locker/127038#127038)

but I couldn't find an answer that solves my problem. I basically created a minified example of how to render a chart with Flot.js to verify that the library is not the problem and this is what I've got:

Chart with LockerService deactivated (chart rendered as expected):
[image]
Chart with Locker service activated(unexpected behavior):
[image]

So basically, Flot.js works fine without LockerService. This library is included using ltng:require tag and the chart is created in afterScriptsLoaded event. The problem is that the chart is not being render as I expected (first screenshot), so I debugged some parts of the code where the chart is set with styles in Flot.js and all seems to be working fine (I expected to see some errors since LockerService restricts the access to  DOM elements between namespaces, but, as far as I see, nothing weird is happening). I also compared the HTML generated of both scenarios and I discovered that the problem is that, for some reason, LockerService prevents the chart's HTML to be updated with inline styles. For example:

One div of the chart correctly rendered is like:

```
<div class="flot-tick-label tickLabel" style="position: absolute; max-width: 141px; top: 432px; left: 98px; text-align: center;">Jan</div>
```

But, with LockerService activated it turns into:

```
<div class="flot-tick-label tickLabel">Jan</div>
```

and so on with the remaining divs/canvas in the chart.

The following js code is inside the controller of the lightning component and it's the code executed on afterScriptsLoaded:

```
({
    onFlotLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        var data = [["1", 3000],["2", 2500],["3", 1000],["4", 500],["5", 3100],["6", 2800]];
        var xticks = [["1", "Jan"],["2", "Feb"],["3", "March"],["4", "March"],["5", "April"],["6", "May"]];
        var options = {
            xaxis : {
                ticks : xticks,
                tickLength : 0,
                autoscaleMargin : .10
            },
            yaxis : {
                axisLabel : "Revenue",
                minTickSize : 1,
                tickFormatter : function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return '$'+x;
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 2
            }
        };

        $.plot("#placeholder", [{
            data : data,
            bars : { show: true, fill: 1, fillColor: "#5B97D5", barWidth: 0.4}
        }], options);
    }
})
```

Is this a LockerService issue? if not, is something wrong with the afterScriptsLoaded code? is there any available workaround?

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: This matches similar problems we are seeing with HighCharts. We are investigating.

Comment: When we had similar issues in HighCharts, it was due to some unknown <rect> coming up in between layer of bars and background. Try giving "fill-opacity: 0;" if some unwanted tags are coming and hiding off your required elements. Basically try a inspect element and see if its loaded to DOM.

Comment: Hi @JFParadis,  thanks for your comment. It seems to be an issue related to LockerService that, apparently, was fixed this week on Salesforce side, on Monday my charts went back to life! yay! (two weeks prior, this bug was present). As far as I could investigate, Salesforce is providing weekly bug fixes for problems like this.

Comment: Hi @PintuFrancis, yeah, I tried to use different js chart libraries but they have similar issues, however, as I mentioned in the other comment, this bug seems to be fixed in Salesforce side because my charts with flot are working again. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this was a LockerService issue, on monday the charts with Flot.js went back to life!.

I consulted this issue in Salesforce forums and they commented me that they improving LockerService and fixing bugs in a weekly basis as users started using it.

Comment: Hi @JoseCarlos, I'm glad to heat that this is now working for you!

Comment: Great to know that. Thanks for the update @Jose Carlos. Hope you have checked in all devices too. For us HighCharts was working initially in all devices except iOS devices. Its working now with minor tweak but not in a smooth way as it used to be on Visualforce pages.